# Dead key functionality with US-Intl layout in Fedora 23

Tags: gnome3, libreoffice, input-method

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/raelgc/win_us_intl) to make the US international with dead keys layout function correctly -- the combination ' + c should give a ç instead of a ć, and more importantly, unsupported combinations should just give both characters in sequence, for example ' + t should output simply 't.

The above works in most applications, even in tty, but for a few, such as Opera and LibreOffice the custom compose table is completely ignored. I've noticed that the variable GTK_IM_MODULE is never set, for some reason, but since GTK applications work fine it doesn't seem to be the issue.

Is there a way to force these applications to use the correct compose table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, right after posting the question I managed to fix the problem.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true
```

did the trick.

Comment: Still after such a long time, this was necessary for me on Fedora 35 with Gnome 40 to actually be able to choose the English AltGr dead keys input scheme. Thank you very much!